# Search Google Place API for places within LatLngBounds on Android

Tags: android, api, search, google-places-api

I am building an Android application that lets users find restaurants in a specific area (LatLngBounds).  I want to do a Google Place search for restaurants that are located inside this LatLngBounds and not outside of it.

I understand that there is a way to do this with the Google Maps JavaScript API V3, however, is there a way to do a Google Place search using LatLngBounds as the location parameter on Android? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some thorough researching, I've realized that there is no easy way to search the Google Place API within a bounds area (LatLngBounds) unless I use the Google Maps JavaScript API V3.

However, there is an alternative solution, which is to use the Yelp API. The Yelp API lets developers specify a "bounding box...defined by a southwest latitude/longitude and a northeast latitude/longitude geographic coordinate."

Here is a link for more information:

http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api

Answer (score 0):

This is late to the party but it seems like with the newer Google Services you can set LatLngBounds for your Places search:

[Here is the API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html#getAutocompletePredictions(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter))

[Here is the Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete)

Comment: No you can't. The bounds that you set using the method getAutocompletePredictions(... , ... , LatLngBounds bounds, ...) will only return "predictions biased towards places in this area". I tried it, and it just helps you find places nearby, it doesn't necessarily gives you places inside the bounds.